# MAMP PRO uninstalled but Terminal commands still exist. How to remove them as well?

Tags: terminal, apache, mysql, php, mamp

> [Source](https://www.mamp.info/en/documentation/):
>   To "uninstall" MAMP, you only have to delete the MAMP directory and
>   everything returns to the original state

I uninstalled MAMP using the Uninstaller from Applications/MAMP PRO. I checked all checkboxes to restore everything. Surprisingly after that, typing `mysql -p` or `php -v` still works:

[image]

I saw that another `MAMP` directory exists in `Applications`. **When I removed** (still stays in the Trash just in case) it I got:

```
slick-mac:~ slick$ php -v
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin/php: No such file or directory
slick-mac:~ slick$ mysql -p
-bash: /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql: No such file or directory
```

and that almost does the trick but finally how to remove all those references. I would like to completely remove those commands (`php`, `mysql`, etc.)

Am I missing some symlinks?

EDIT:

I've found this for `php` in `/usr/bin`

```
slick-mac:bin slick$ ls -alh | grep php
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel    10M 18 Oct 09:47 php
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel   3.2K  9 Sep 17:30 php-config
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel   4.4K 23 Aug 11:22 phpize
slick-mac:bin slick$ pwd
/usr/bin
```

should I remove those 3 items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I forgot about `.bash_profile`

```
alias mysql='/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql -u root -p'
export PATH=/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/bin:$PATH
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably you added one or more bin directories (containing mysql and php) to your $PATH. Remove them.

The three php* files in /usr/bin belong to the default OS X system and are completely legit.